# "hadoop namenode -format" returns a java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, configuration, hadoop, hdfs

I'm currently learning hadoop and I'm trying to setup a single node test as defined in http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/single_node_setup.html

I've configured ssh (I can log without a password).

My server is on our intranet, behind a proxy.

When I'm trying to run

> bin/hadoop namenode -format

I get the following  java.net.UnknownHostException exception:

```
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
11/06/10 15:36:47 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = java.net.UnknownHostException: srv-clc-04.univ-nantes.prive3: srv-clc-04.univ-nantes.prive3
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.203.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20-security-203 -r 1099333; compiled by 'oom' on Wed May  4 07:57:50 PDT 2011
************************************************************/
Re-format filesystem in /home/lindenb/tmp/HADOOP/dfs/name ? (Y or N) Y
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO util.GSet: 2% max memory = 19.1675 MB
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=lindenb
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO common.Storage: Image file of size 113 saved in 0 seconds.
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /home/lindenb/tmp/HADOOP/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.
11/06/10 15:36:50 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at java.net.UnknownHostException: srv-clc-04.univ-nantes.prive3: srv-clc-04.univ-nantes.prive3
************************************************************/
```

After that, hadoop was started

```
./bin/start-all.sh
```

but there was another new exception when I tried to copy a local file:

```
 bin/hadoop fs  -copyFromLocal ~/file.txt  file.txt

DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/lindenb/file.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1417)
```

how can I fix this problem please ?

Thanks

Comment: I am receiving a similar error when formatting my NameNode on the Cloudera distribution in a CentOS virtual machine. Can you please tell me what you did to your /etc/hosts file? I currently have the following lines:

Comment: `127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost` and `::1          localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[UnknownHostException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) is thrown when hadoop tries to resolve the DNS name (srv-clc-04.univ-nantes.prive3) to an ip address. This fails.

Look for the domain name in the configuration files and replace it by "localhost". (Or update the DNS up resolve the name to an ip address)

Comment: Thanks, I added an alias in /etc/hosts

Comment: Thanks, I too had the same issu updating /etc/hosts file helped

Answer (score 4):

First get the host name of your computer. It can be obtained by running `$hostname` command.
Then add `127.0.0.1 localhost hostname` into the `/etc/hosts` file. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The tmp directory that you have created should have ownership issues. That is why hadoop is not able to write to the tmp directoy to fix it run the following commands

```
sudo chown hduser:hadoop /app/<your hadoop tmp dir>
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending the below to `/etc/hosts` may help:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   yourhostname
```