# $ bin/hadoop namenode -format STARTUP_MSG: host = java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration

I'm currently learning Hadoop by http://tecadmin.net/steps-to-install-hadoop-on-centosrhel-6/
in the 5th step when I apply this command $ bin/hadoop namenode -format I get following error [image]

I also have checked these links for resolving my problem 
["hadoop namenode -format" returns a java.net.UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307244/hadoop-namenode-format-returns-a-java-net-unknownhostexception)
[java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid hostname for server: local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484275/what-causes-the-error-java-net-unknownhostexception)
I don't know where is domain name in the configuration files for replacing it by localhost.
also I went to /etc/hosts file and replaced text by localhost.. still I haven't resolve the problem please someone help me.

Comment: Can u please attach your /etc/hosts file here..? and how many node you are running..?

Comment: before editing it was like this(127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6) now I have edited with this (127.0.0.1 localhost static.98.35.ebonenet.com) and its running.. thanks.

Comment: got you..you are Wlcm.!

Answer (score 6):

The unknownHostException could be resolved by the following steps:

- Go to /etc/hosts
- Edit the "hosts" file with IP 127.0.0.1 [space] HostName (e.g. static.98.35.ebonenet.com)
- Save the file and try again

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Aadil's answer I resolved The unknownHostException by the following steps:

Step-1 Go to /etc/hosts
Step-2 Edit the "hosts" file with IP 127.0.0.1 [space/tab] localhost [space/tab] HostName (e.g. static.98.35.ebonenet.com)
Step-3 Save the file and try again

Comment: My /etc/hosts file is correct and yarn configuration is working fine. the nodes are running DataNode and are reported in Yarn node list. I am getting this exception while executing my MapReduce application. Any idea why is it like and where shall I look for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
If anyone facing:

> SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   ubuntu: ubuntu: unknown error

**Solution:**

- Go to /etc/hosts
- Disable/Remove if any IPV6 configuration maintained in /etc/hosts file
- Save the file and try again