# getting error while starting hdfs namenode -format

Tags: hadoop

I'm installing hadoop on remote server when starting
hdfs namenode -format
getting error java.net.UnknownHostException: Web: Web: unknown error
i have configure all required file

```
16/10/14 14:28:38 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = java.net.UnknownHostException: Web: Web: unknown error
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.7.3
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.3-tests.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.3-tests.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.3-tests.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.3.jar:/opt/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r baa91f7c6bc9cb92be5982de4719c1c8af91ccff; compiled by 'root' on 2016-08-18T01:41Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_101
************************************************************/
16/10/14 14:28:38 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/10/14 14:28:38 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
16/10/14 14:28:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Formatting using clusterid: CID-ee9a072b-1347-476a-a57d-8752d8cceb6f
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: No KeyProvider found.
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=true
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.namenode.startup.delay.block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: The block deletion will start around 2016 Oct 14 14:28:39
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 889 MB = 17.8 MB
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog          = 1000
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = hadoop (auth:SIMPLE)
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 889 MB = 8.9 MB
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: ACLs enabled? false
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: XAttrs enabled? true
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Maximum size of an xattr: 16384
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 889 MB = 2.2 MB
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^18 = 262144 entries
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.num.buckets = 10
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.users = 10
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.minutes = 1,5,25
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
16/10/14 14:28:39 WARN net.DNS: Unable to determine local hostname -falling back to "localhost"
java.net.UnknownHostException: Web: Web: unknown error
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.resolveLocalHostname(DNS.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.<clinit>(DNS.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newBlockPoolID(NNStorage.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newNamespaceInfo(NNStorage.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1559)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Web: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
    ... 8 more
16/10/14 14:28:39 WARN net.DNS: Unable to determine address of the host-falling back to "localhost" address
java.net.UnknownHostException: Web: Web: unknown error
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.resolveLocalHostIPAddress(DNS.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.<clinit>(DNS.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newBlockPoolID(NNStorage.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newNamespaceInfo(NNStorage.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1559)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Web: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
    ... 8 more
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-473584576-127.0.0.1-1476435519338
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /opt/hadoop/hadoopdata/namenode has been successfully formatted.
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Saving image file /opt/hadoop/hadoopdata/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Image file /opt/hadoop/hadoopdata/namenode/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 of size 353 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
16/10/14 14:28:39 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at java.net.UnknownHostException: Web: Web: unknown error
************************************************************/
```

#### environment variable

```xml
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_101
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/jre/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

#### core-site.xml

```xml
<property>
     <name>fs.default.name</name>
     <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

#### yarn-site.xml

```xml
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```

#### hdfs-site.xml

```xml
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:///opt/hadoop/hadoopdata/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:///opt/hadoop/hadoopdata/datanode</value>
</property>
```

#### mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

#### yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["hadoop namenode -format" returns a java.net.UnknownHostException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307244/hadoop-namenode-format-returns-a-java-net-unknownhostexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `/etc/hosts` file, format should be like below

```
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost
192.168.10.11   abc.com   abc
192.168.10.12   xyz.com   xyz
```

And check your machine `hostname`

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to hadoop